# Ajax Accordion and IE8 rendering problem

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an accordion control that is generated in code. Earlier today it stopped rendering correctly in IE8. It would function ok, but sometimes the layout would get corrupted, and all kinds of weird graphical glitches occured. It did not fail in firefox.

I reset my IE settings to factory defaults and it fixed it. It works perfectly on another test machine, but on some of the machines on our network the graphical issues occur.

Has anyone else experienced the same or know a fix? All of our computers run internet explorer 8. If it becomes a big problem I will try forcing compatibility mode but I would prefer a more permenant fix (and also that might not even fix the issue!).

Answer (score 2):

I've had issues like this in the past, most typically an issue with some CSS settings.  If you use the developer tools in IE, look to see what CSS settings are being applied and try to rule that out.

A screenshot of what is happening and what should happen would be useful along with the code sample.

Answer (score 2):

On your accordion headers only, place the following css code:

.accordionHeader { display: table; width: 100%; }

If you find that the headers still jump when hovering between them, use a border-top using a solid colour rather than using margin and padding. Of course this only works on designs ontop of solid colours (the border colour would need to match the background colour). Heres an example:

.accordionHeader { border-top: 10px solid #FFFFFF; }

This will fix IE8 right up! This has taken me a year to figure out lol.

Comment: display:table and a hardcoded width worked perfectly for me - thanks!